# Google App Engine - PHP - Serve Static Files from Composer - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, composer-php, php-7.2, appengine-wordpress

I have a very basic application on App Engine, set up with PHP 7.2.

In the [official documentation of installing WP on GAE PHP 7.2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/wordpress), they wrote a script that copies WordPress files, and then you commit and deploy them.

This composer configuration uses [`johnpbloch/wordpress`](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress) together with [`composer/installers`](http://composer.github.io/installers/), to download and install WordPress to `wp` folder upon `composer install`, so I don't have to commit nor deploy this code.

The `composer.json` file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "ext-phar": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "^1.3",
    "symfony/console": "^3.0",
    "google/cloud-tools": "^0.8.5",
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "^5.0.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.5",
    "composer/installers": "^1.6"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "wp/wp-content/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "wp/wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "wp/wp-content/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
  }
}
```

`.gcloudignore` file:

```
.gcloudignore

# Git
.git
.gitignore

# PHP Composer dependencies
vendor
wp
```

and `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:    
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wp/\1
  upload: wp/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|htm|html|css|js)$
```

So, GAE successfully deploys and builds the project.

The default handler (`index.php`) seems to have access to `vendor` folder, e.g. when writing `require __DIR__.'/wp/index.php'` it works.

BUT it will not serve the static files. Going to a URL like `<project>.appspot.com/wp-includes/images/media/audio.png` returns 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2019, there is no such option in Google App Engine PHP 7 Standard.

- You **can** `statically serve` only files you **directly deploy**.
- You **cannot** `statically serve` any files **installed by composer**.

By `statically serve`, I mean to use `static_dir` or `static_files` handlers in your `app.yaml` ([read more](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_static_files)).

This information is from a discussion with a Google Support representative.

*I am waiting on the Support Team to create a feature request, and will attach the link here.*

Comment: Your feature request is forwarded to the App Engine product team for further process. You may star [the public ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/122644831) to receive further updates on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.yaml is referencing **`wp/`** directory whereas your URL is looking for **`wp-includes/`** directory. See the documentation of **[static_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers)** for details.

Comment: this is exactly the behavior that I expect, which is not working. URL of `<project>.appspot.com/wp-includes/<file>` should serve from `\wp\wp-includes\<file>`

Answer (score 0):

The way your `app.yaml` is set up, a call to `<project>.appspot.com/wp-includes/images/media/audio.png` will try to upload from the directory:

```
/wp/wp-includes/images/media/audio.png
```

Is that the way your files are nested? Is the `wp` directory at the root of your project?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited the question.
`wp` folder is automatically created, together with `vendor`, when running `composer install`.